# Match hash inclusion

Tags: php, regex, match

Pretty basic, how can I take `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` and include `#`.

Comment: [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: @PranavCBalan those examples were did not work in my scenario for some reason. The answer below did the trick for some odd reason. I hope it to be explained. I now need to know how to do the same in .htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add any extra characters you want to allow to the character class.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_#-]
           ↑
```

**Additional note**: (*in case you're getting an invalid range error*)

Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special meaning**. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.

Comment: Hey that did the trick! Where did you pick that up? **Now** how can I apply this in .htaccess?

Comment: I did read that and I probably implemented, but the string is being matched between two different files. I may have accidentally omitted that revision. But thank you, and please, any insight on the .htaccess, or if you recommend asking a new question...

Comment: If you have another question regarding `.htaccess` post it separate.

Comment: I figured as much (have to wait 90 minutes). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this too

```
[\w-#]
```

`\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`-` matches the character `-` literally

`#` matches the character `#` literally

Comment: Yes, I actually tried many of these without luck. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Never mind - you were right :) there are several instances. It's still early. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @jarmerson Happy coding :)